# how to solve the rowid (Pseudocolumn) of oracle in postgres

Tags: postgresql, oracle, database-migration, edb

oracle has something called row id which nothing but a Pseudo column, is there any alternative of that present in postgres and EDB. if yes that what is that and if not how I can solve this issue.

for refernce

```
SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(2) FULL(t) */ 
rowid, account_id, service_id, charge_date
FROMemployee %s t;
```

Comment: Whyt is it required anyway?? rowid is just a simple hexedecimal pointer to a location.If the you have asked for rownum that would have been considered.On the other hand you can use rank() over partition  by <primary key> to get rownums in postgres.

Answer (score 1):

The correct replacement is the *primary key* of the table.

PostgreSQL does have an equivalent to Oracle's `ROWID`, which is `ctid`, but owing to the different implementation, that value changes with every update and cannot be used to reliably identify a table row across different SQL statements.

Comment: Oracle's `ROWID` can change (one example is if you have row-movement enabled) but it should be able to reliably identify rows within a single transaction. You should not rely on it across different transactions though.

Comment: @MT0 Yes, I know. But row movement is disabled by default, right? So while using `ROWID`s across transactions may be slightly unsafe in Oracle, it definitely won't work with `ctid` in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple workaround for it:

```
select rank() over (partition by <primary key> order by <primary key>) as rn,* 
from <tablename>;
```